# Laravel, how can I overwrite code from vendor

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.1 has this code:

```
public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

    $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    });

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));/*I HAVE TO CHANGE THIS*/
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }
}
```

That code it's from a trait:
`app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords.php`

I need to change the line with the comment with another code:

```
return redirect()->route('login')->with(['message' => 'Se ha enviado a su email el link del reseteo, por favor verifique.',]);
```

But it's a vendor file. How can I do this? overwrite the method in another file? where?

Comment: Have you tried inheriting the class and overiding the `postEmail` method?

Comment: The code is from a trait, should I extend the class that uses that trait? The class `PasswordController` use `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;` and which is a trait, the method `postEmail()`is there

Comment: If some endpoint is calling this function post Email, one way would be to override this function as you wish and then define this route in your routes file with your overriden method.

Comment: The trait "add" methods to the class kinda like inheritance. You can override `postEmail` by creating your own `postEmail` method. When the route will call the action `ResetPasswordController@postEmail` (or whatever was is name on 5.1), it will call your instead of vendor.

Answer (score 1):

One slightly hacky solution would be to copy the class you need to edit, and place it in `somedir/fixed_class.php` with the original namespace and class name. Then add to composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
     "files": ["somedir/fixed_class.php"]
  }
```

However you're better off to somehow try to extend the class and use your own improved version (or submit a bugfix/feature request for the original composer module).

Answer (score 0):

The `back()` function will check the `referer` header in request, so you can write a middleware that change that to `url(route('login'))`.

If that header is not set, you can call `$request->setPreviousUrl(url(route('login')))`;

So basically your Middleware code can be something like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (/* request is the reset password */) {
        if ($request->headers->has('referer')) {
            $request->headers->set('referer', url(route('login')));
        } else {
            $request->setPreviousUrl(url(route('login')));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not only the route, it's also the parameters of `with` that I need to change. Teh default has only `status` and it's string, I need more parameters (an array of them)

Comment: Once you are in the `login` controller action, you can add to your session other parameters. Something like (it's pseudo-code): `if (session()->has('status')) { session()->put('message', 'your message'); }`